# Add class names to React root component or change structure

Tags: reactjs, css-selectors, components, classname

I am trying to use flexbox with a React component but a root div is being inserted. I can't add class names to the root div (omitted).

I think it could be split out into smaller components but I am not sure how?

This is how the structure is now:

[image]

This is how I would like the structure:

[image]

Current (trimmed down) App.js code:

```
const Hit = ({hit}) =>
  <div className="col-xl-3 col-lg-4 col-md-6 col-sm-12 d-flex align-items-stretch var-result">
    <div className="card">
      <div className="card-block">
        <div className="row flex-wrap">
            <div className="col-md-8"><h4><Highlight attributeName="name" hit={hit}/></h4></div>
            <div className="col-md-4 text-right">
              <img src={hit.image} className="img-fluid" alt=""/>
            </div>
        </div>
        <p className="d-inline-block db-name">Database name</p>
        <p className="d-inline-block vendor-name">${hit.price}</p>
        <p className="card-text small"><Highlight attributeName="description" hit={hit}/></p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

const SearchResultContent = () =>
  <section className="row grey-bg mt-5 overflow-y">
    <Hits hitComponent={Hit} className="d-flex flex-wrap"/>
  </section>


class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <InstantSearch
        appId="latency"
        apiKey="3d9875e51fbd20c7754e65422f7ce5e1"
        indexName="bestbuy">

        <HeaderNav />
        <div className="container-fluid">
          <div className="row">
            <SideBar/>
            <Main/>
            <SearchResultContent/>
          </div>
      </div>
    </InstantSearch>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

The classNames that are not added to the inserted root element.

```
<Hits hitComponent={Hit} className="d-flex flex-wrap"/>
```

Comment: Did you ever find an answer?

Comment: Unfortunately not. 

I think I was using a plugin shopping cart? This question has gone stale (2+ years old).

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if I understood, but I think you need to pass these extra classes as props, like:

```
<Hits hitComponent={Hit} classNames="d-flex flex-wrap"/>
```

then:

```
const Hits = ({hit, classNames }) =>
  <div className={classNames}>
     
    ...
    
  </div>
```

Hope it helps.